# Passing an 2-dimensional array to function and changing the values in it

Tags: c

I have a 2 dimensional array and i am passing it into a function and changing the values in the array

```
#define numRows 3
#define numCols 7
#define TotalNum (numRows*numCols)

int arr[numRows][numCols] = {{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}, {7,8,9,10,11,12,13},{14,15,16,17,18,19,20}};

1) random_rearrange_num(arr);

2) random_rearrange_num(arr);

void random_rearrange_num(int p[][numCols])
{
  int temp = 0,k= 0,l = 0;
  for(int i = numRows -1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
  {
    for (int j = numCols-1;j>0; j--)
    {
          k = 0 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(2-0+1)+1);
          l= 0 + rand()/(RAND_MAX/(6-0+1)+1);
          temp = p[i][j]; 
          p[i][j] = p[k][l];
          p[k][l] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, i am calling `random_rearrange_num` twice to randomly rearrange the numbers in the 2-d array.

But have some errors when i try to compile:

At point 1)

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int [3][7]' to 'int'

At point 2)

> error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Not sure what these errors are and how to correct them. Need some guidance on it...

I have only posted a bit of the code. The full code is here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/programming-of-3-x-7-trick

Comment: Show as real code. (where is `main`? is there any difference between `point 1` and `point 2`?)

Answer (score 1):

In line 22 (`int row = 0,`), you should replace the comma by a semicolon. (Since you haven't a `;`, the compiler thinks that the `random_rearrange_num(arr)` is an int declaration)

BTW, your code is `c++`. not `c`.

Comment: how do u know it is C++ and not C?

Comment: to make it to C, i just need to remove the references and just make it return the value of row..am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a `main()` function to call `random_rearrange_num()`.